# Expectation of $|U|$ given the first and second moments of $U$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let U be a random variable with $E(U)=0,Var(U)<\infty$, is it true that $E(|U|)<\infty$?

Comment: Yes, and the proof is a one-liner: $$|x| \leq 1+x^2 ~~\forall\, x \implies E[|X|] \leq 1 + E[X^2] = 1+\operatorname{var}(X) < \infty.$$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz $$ E|XY| \leq \sqrt{ E(X^2) E(Y^2)}$$ Put $Y=1$

Comment: It's not even a one-liner, because by the very definition of expectation, $E(U)$ is defined and finite if and only if the expectations of the positive part $U^{+}=\max(U,0)$ and negative part $U^{-}=\max(-U,0)$ are finite; and by the definition of absolute value, $|U|=U^{+}+U^{-}$; so--apart from invoking linearity of expectation--all you have to note is that the sum of two finite numbers is finite.